# Is following function valid to be a copula function?

Tags: statistics

I know $C(u,v)=uv$ is a copula corresponding to the independent case. How about $C(u,v)=u^2v^2$?

Comment: This is not a copula. You can find a discussion of copulas with quadratic section in Nelsen, *An introduction to copulas*, second edition, 2006, pp. 77-80.

Answer (score 3):

A bivariate copula $C:[0,1]^2 \to [0,1]$ must satisfy

$$\tag{1} C(u,0) = C(0,v) = 0,$$
$$\tag{2} C(u,1) = C(1,u) = u,$$

and, if $0 \leqslant u_1 \leqslant u_2 \leqslant 1$ and $0 \leqslant v_1 \leqslant v_2 \leqslant 1,$

$$\tag{3} C(u_2,v_2) - C(u_2,v_1) - C(u_1,v_2) + C(u_1,v_1) \geqslant 0  $$

In this case condition (2) is violated.

Condition (2) is required because given random variables $X_1, X_2$ with marginal distributions $F_1, F_2$ we must have, for example,

$$\begin{align}C(u,1) &= P(X_1 \leqslant F_1^{-1}(u),X_2 \leqslant F_2^{-1}(1)) \\ &=  P(X_1 \leqslant F_1^{-1}(u)) \\ &= F_1(F_1^{-1}(u)) \\ &= u \end{align}$$